# Eclipse :The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE .
When i tried to build the Applicaion , its giving me this error under Problems view

Description

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.ejb.EJBObject. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

Type

```
Java Problem
The type javax.ejb.EJBObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Comment: So you have to add the JAR containg `EJBObject` to your build path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have a simple Java project and not an web project.  You are missing a Server Runtime that provides the EjbObject to your project.

Either try converting the project by right-clicking, "Convert To", "Faceted Project", and select the appropriate Java EE configurations for your use case or create a new project with a Java EE nature and copy your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Incase of weblogic you have to add server runtime POM dependency - wlthint3client :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
        <version>10.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   I went through same error and i found solution.You can import external jar file JAVAX.ejb.jar and configure it in your project.
```

> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxejbjar.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem.

I was missing to select the server in the project facet. After doing that, it solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the configuration of the libraries, so basically eclipse was trying to use at Properties -> Libraries the JRE that comes embedded with Eclipse, so I just changed the path of JRE to point on my downloaded JRE and the error was vanished